# caffe: convolution with a fix predifined kernel (filter)

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

Instead of having a learnable filter, I am interested in a convolution with a fix predefined matrix; for example sobel filter:

[image]

so, I set learning = 0 (so its fixed), and my kernel size = 3 as:

```
layer {
    name: "conv1"
    type: "Convolution"
    bottom: "data"
    top: "conv1"
    param { lr_mult: 0 decay_mult: 0 }
    convolution_param {
      num_output: 10
      kernel_size: 3    # filter is 3x3
      stride: 2          
      weight_filler {
        type: ??}
    }
  }
```

Now, I do not know how to give matrix information to the conv layer. Any ideas? I think it should go to weight_filler, but how?

One more question: num_output has to be same as bottom's (data channel = 10 here) channel size? can I set num_output another number? if yes, what will happen and what that means?

Comment: `weight_filler` is only defined for very few predefined filters. Check out net_surgery tutorial to see how you can manipulate weights in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to init weights to specific values?

You can use [`net_surgery`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb) to load your untrained/un-initialized net in python and then assign the specific weights you want to the filters, save the net, and use it with the weights you want for this specific layer.

#### How do set `num_output` and other `conv_params`?

This is a good question: You have an input blob of shape `b`x`10`x`h`x`w` and you want to apply a `3`x`3` filter to each channel and get back a new filtered `b`x`10`x`h`x`w`. If you just set `num_output: 10`, the shape of the filters would be `10`x`10`x`3`x`3`, that is, 10 filters of shape `10`x`3`x`3` - which is **not** want you expect. You want a `3`x`3` filter.
To that end you need to look at [`group`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/convolution.html) conv_param. Setting `group: 10` together with `num_output: 10` (assuming input c=10) will give you what you want, the weight shape will be `10`x`1`x`3`x`3`.

Answer (score 0):

In python caffe interface, `caffe.Net` object instatiated with loading `.prototxt` file, which defined the network architecture. You can use `caffe.Net` object with following properties for accessing various information on the network.

- **`blob_loss_weights`**: An OrderedDict (bottom to top, i.e., input to output) of network blob loss weights indexed by layer name
- **`blobs`**: An OrderedDict (bottom to top, i.e., input to output) of network blobs indexed by layer name
- **`bottom_names`**: all bottom names in the network
- **`inputs`**: inputs to this network
- **`layer_dict`**: An OrderedDict (bottom to top, i.e., input to output) of network layers indexed by layer name
- **`layers`**: `caffe._caffe.LayerVec` - list of whose element is `caffe.Layer` objects in the network, `caffe.Layer` classs has `blobs` field for layer's parameters memory and `type` for layer type (e.g, Convolution, Data, etc)
- **`outputs`**: outputs from this network
- **`params`**: An OrderedDict (bottom to top, i.e., input to output) of network parameters indexed by name; each is a list of multiple blobs (e.g., weights and biases)
- **`top_names`**: all top names in the network

---

You can use **`caffe.Net.params`** for accessing layer's learnable parameters together with **`caffe.Net.layer_dict`** to access layer info.

**`caffe.Net.params`** is ordered dictionary where key is layer name and value is the blobs for parameters (e.g, weight and bias) and in case of Convolution layer, first element of blobs are weiht and second element of blobs is bias:

- `caffe.Net.params['layer_name'][0]` : weight
- `caffe.Net.params['layer_name'][1]` : bias

Please note that access to blob's memory should be done with `caffe.Net.params['layer_name'][0].data` and updating the blob's memory should be done with `...` such as `caffe.Net.params['layer_name'][0].data[...]`

Following code illustrate the loading learnable parameter from numpy saved file (.npy):

```py
def load_weights_and_biases(network):
    k_list = list(network.params.keys())

    suffix = ["weight", "bias"]
    num_layers = len(network.layer_dict)
    
    for idx, layer_name in enumerate(network.layer_dict):
        print(f"\n-----------------------------")
        print(f"layer index: {idx}/{num_layers}")
        print(f"layer name: '{layer_name}''")
        print(f"layer type: '{detection_nw.layers[idx].type}' ")
        
        if layer_name in k_list:
            params = network.params[layer_name]
            print(f"{len(params)} learnable parameters in '{detection_nw.layers[idx].type}' type")        
            
            for i, p in enumerate(params):
                #print(f"\tparams[{i}]: {p}")
                #print(f"\tparams[{i}] CxHxW: {p.channels}x{p.height}x{p.width}")
                print(f"\tp[{i}]: {p.data.shape} of {p.data.dtype}")
                
                                
                param_file_path = f"./npy_save/{layer_name}_{suffix[i]}.npy"
                
                param_file = Path(param_file_path)
                if param_file.exists():
                    print(f"\tload {param_file_path}")
                    arr = np.load(param_file_path, allow_pickle=True)
                    
                    if p.data.shape == arr.shape:
                        print(f"\tset {layer_name}_{suffix[i]} with arr:shape {arr.shape}, type {arr.dtype}")
                                                
                        p.data[...] = arr
                        
                    else:
                        print(f"p.data.shape: {p.data.shape} is not equal to arr.shape: {arr.shape}")
                        break
                else:
                    print(f"{param_file_path} is not exits!!")
                    break                       
        else:
            print(f"no learnable parameters in '{layer_name}' of '{network.layers[idx].type}' type'")
```

Blob type is defined as **`caffe._caffe.Blob`** in python caffe (aka pycaffe) interface. Use `help(caffe._caffe.Blob)` after `import caffe` and names described in **data descriptors defined here** section of help output as attribute.

For more detaild info on Blob in Caffe reference

> - [Blobs, Layers, and Nets: anatomy of a Caffe model](https://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/net_layer_blob.html) - caffe documentations
> - [caffe::Blob Class Template Reference](https://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1Blob.html) - C++ source for Blob class